# Where can I find Exchange 2003 to 2010 migration resources? (project plan, etc)

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2003, migration

Does anyone know of a online migration plan, or list of steps that can be turned into one?  I'm migrating from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps?

http://milindn.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/rapid-transition-guide-from-exchange-2003-to-exchange-2010.pdf

found on:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchange2010/thread/bb9a5a3c-119a-4d66-9b1e-2bfc1028cb98

Answer (score 1):

[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com) almost always has good planning and deployment resources, including [Exchange 2003->2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998186.aspx)

<sub>Note: Exchange 2007/10 is a much more complicate piece of software from the old Exchange 2K/3 models. If that roadmap seems very confusing, you probably haven't studied Exchange 2010's architecture enough to understand the ramification of upgrading.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'd asked for insight from the community in [my question here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/178772/experiences-in-upgrading-from-exchange-2003-to-exchange-2010)  I received some good pointers there.