# Exchange 2003-Exchange 2010 post migration GAL/OAB problem

Tags: outlook, exchange, migration, exchange-2010

I am very new to Exchange so forgive my newbie-ness. I've exhausted Google trying to find a way to solve my problem so I'm hoping some of you gurus can shed some light on my next steps. Please forgive my bungling around through this.

**The problem**

I cannot download/update the Global Address List (GAL) and Offline Address Book (OAB) on my Outlook 2010 clients. I get:

```
Task 'emailaddress' reported error (0x8004010F) : 'The operation failed. An object cannot be found.' ---- error.
```

I'm using cached exchange mode, which if I turn off Outlook hangs completely from the moment I start it up. (Note I've replaced my actual email address with 'emailaddress')

**Background information**

I migrated mailboxes, public store, etc. from a Small Business Server 2003 with Exchange 2003 box to a Server 2008 R2 with Exchange 2010 based primarily on an experts exchange how to article. The exchange server is up and running as an internet facing exchange server with all of the roles necessary to send and receive mail and in that capacity is working fine.

I "thought" I had successfully migrated everything from the SBS03 box, and due to huge amounts of errors in everything from AD to the Exchange install itself I removed the reference to the SBS03 server in adsiedit. I've still got access to the old SBS03 box, but as I said the number of errors in everything is preventing even the uninstall of Exchange (or the starting of the Exchange Information Store service), so I'm quite content to leave that box completely out of the picture while trying to solve my problem.

After research I discovered this is most likely because I failed to run the `“update-globaladdresslist”` (or get / update) command from the Exchange shell before I removed the Exchange 2003 server from adsiedit (and the network). If I run the command now it gives me:

```
    WARNING: The recipient "domainname.com/Microsoft Exchange System Objects/Offline Address Book - first administrative group" is invalid and couldn't be updated.  
    WARNING: The recipient "domainname.com/Microsoft Exchange System Objects/Schedule+ Free Busy Information – first administrative group" is invalid and couldn't be updated.  
    WARNING: The recipient "domainname.com/Microsoft Exchange System Objects/ContainernameArchive" is invalid and couldn't be updated.  
    WARNING: The recipient "domainname.com/Microsoft Exchange System Objects/ContainernameContacts" is invalid and couldn't be updated.
```

(Note that I’ve replaced my domain with “domainname.com” and my organization name with “containername”)

**What I’ve tried**

I don’t want to use the old OAB, or GAL, I don’t care about either, our GAL and distribution lists needed to be organized anyway, so at this point I really just want to get rid of the old reference to the “first administrative group” and move on. I’ve tried to create a new GAL and tell Exchange 2010 to use that GAL instead of the old GAL, but I'm obviously missing some of the commands or something dumb I need to do to start over with a blank slate/GAL/OAB.

I'm very tempted to completely delete the entire "first administrative group" tree from adsiedit and see if that gets rid of the ridiculous reference that no longer exists but I dont want to break something else.

Commands run to try to create a new GAL and tell exch10 to use that GAL:

```
New-globaladdresslist –name NAMEOFNEWGAL

Set-globaladdresslist GUID –name NAMEOFNEWGAL
```

This did nothing for me except now when I run get-globaladdresslist or with the | FL pipe I see two GALs listed, the “default global address list” and the “NAMEOFNEWGAL” that I created.

After a little more research this morning it looks like you can't change/delete/remove the default address list, and the only way to do what I'm trying to do would be to maybe remove the default address list via adsiedit and recreate with a command something like `new-GlobalAddressList -Name "Default Global Address List" -IncludedRecipients AllRecipients`. This would be acceptable but I've searched and searched and can't find instructions or a breakdown of where exactly the default GAL lives in AD, and if I'd have to remove multiple child references/records.

**Of interest**

I'm getting an event ID 9337 in my application log `OALGen did not find any recipients in address list \Global Address List`. This offline address list will not be generated. -`\NAMEOFMYOAB ---------` on my Exchange 2010 box, which pretty much to me seems to confirm my suspicion that the empty GAL/OAB is what's causing the Outlook client `0x8004010F` error.

Help please!

Comment: This link may be of help? http://microsoft-server-operating-systems.hostweb.com/TopicMessages/microsoft.public.windows.server.sbs/1971690/1/Default.aspx

Comment: Your quickest fix may be to poke around the previously asked questions here ( this one has some great links http://serverfault.com/questions/178772/experiences-in-upgrading-from-exchange-2003-to-exchange-2010 )

Comment: OK so did you delete the actual First Administrative Group object in AD? What about the GAL or OAB? Did you delete those?

Answer (score 0):

Partially resolved with http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000516.htm. Hope this helps someone in future.